# is it possible communication between two clients of sip voip server withoust dialing phone number?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sip, voip

I want to develop sip voip application. I want to communicate between two users of sip voip server but not communication between our phone contact users. I have seen many example like siphon, linphone, idoubs but it is not direct communication between logged users of sip voip.

I don't want to dial and sms to our phone contact users. I want to only communication between sip user to user.

so, please give any suggestion or source code which is apply in my app.

Thank You...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can create button on your softphone which will call pre-defined number.

You also can create users list and call from that list.

Or you can get any softphone with sip&jabber support and use that.